# How to search for regex in a file, then modify all occurrences in-place?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, in-place

I want to search a file for lines that match this regex: `AB[0-9][0-9]-XYZ` and then simply edit the file in place so that char string now has the literal chars `Linux\` in front of it. For example lets say the following strings exist in a file:

```
AB62-XYZ
AB10-XYZ
```

I simply need those to become:

```
Linux\AB62-XYZ
Linux\AB10-XYZ
```

Just to clarify, the strings I am looking for can and do occur anywhere in the file, not necessarily at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution in Ex/Vi editor:

```
ex -s +'%s/\(AB[0-9][0-9]-XYZ\)/Linux\\\1/g' -cwq foo.txt
```

Which is more compatible in comparison to `sed`, as in-place (`-i`) option is non-standard FreeBSD extensions, so it has different syntax between Unix and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

use `sed -i 's/\(AB[0-9][0-9]-XYZ\)/Linux\\\1/g' file` and it's it

Comment: I should have been more clear, the strings i'm looking for don't start at beginning of a line.